# Add an ancestor class to all selectors in SASS but also keep the original selectors

Tags: sass

It's easy to add an ancestor class to all my selectors in SASS.

For instance, if I have this in a file called **module.scss**

```
.module {}
.module-heading {}
```

I can do something like this:

```
.ancestor-class {
    @import "module.scss";
}
```

And I will get this:

```
.ancestor-class .module {}
.ancestor-class .module-heading {}
```

**However, I would like to also keep the original selector and get this instead:**

```
.module,
.ancestor-class .module {}

.module-heading,
.ancestor-class .module-heading {}
```